# European Characters are not displayed

Tags: html, utf-8

I have some issues with displaying European characters

Here is my Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Image2Food - 
Sag mir, was ich daraus kochen kann - Index
</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
<div id="nav">
<?php
require("nav.php")
?>
</div>
<div id="content">
<h1>Image2Food - Sag mir, was ich daraus kochen kann</h1>
<h2>Das soziale, multimediale Netzwerk für Kochideen</h2>
```

On Main page the letter "ü", "ä" and "ö" are diplayed as "?". I can not explain why.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: Maybe it's a Brexit-based code?

Comment: Ha Ha..Brexit Code

Comment: No, nothing is duplicate

Comment: All the information you need is already given by the link I posted.

Comment: Why would you tag `PHP` for something that's clearly pure `HTML`? Just because you include some php file doesn't mean your question has anything to do with it..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved it this way:

```
<?php
/**
* Festlegung der Untergrenze für die PHP-Version
*@version: 1.0
*/
if (0 > version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5')) {
die('<h1>Für diese Anwendung '.
'ist mindestens PHP 5 notwendig</h1>');
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />
<title>Image2Food - 
Sag mir, was ich daraus kochen kann - Index
</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
<div id="nav">
<?php
require("nav.php")
?>
</div>
<div id="content">
<?php
```

Answer (score 1):

In your document you are declaring the UTF-8 character encoding (good idea).  For this to work the editor/viewer you are using to edit the file must also be in UTF-8 mode.

If, for example, your editor was in "ANSI" (latin-1 or CP1252) mode, then they would look fine in your editor, but when the browser, in UTF-8 mode, tries to interpret those bytes they will look like invalid byte sequences.

If your editor does not support UTF-8 mode or this is not practical for some reason, use numeric character entities.  For example, `ü` is `&#x00FC;`.  You can use [this tool](https://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/) to convert.  Paste the sentence into the top box, and then press convert above the box, then look into the box that says "Hex NCRs".

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

it looks like you using German language in your some part of html I would suggest you to add below tag where ever you would like to use German language.

```
<blockquote lang="de">


</blockquote>
```

for example :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="de">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Image2Food - 
    Sag mir, was ich daraus kochen kann - Index
    </title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="nav">
    <?php
    require("nav.php")
    ?>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
    <blockquote lang="de">
    <h1>Image2Food - Sag mir, was ich daraus kochen kann</h1>
    <h2>Das soziale, multimediale Netzwerk für Kochideen</h2>
    </blockquote>
```

Comment: Thank you for your Suggestion, but it doesn't work this way